# Reading parameters like signup[product][handle] in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to read parameters from Context.Request that is written in a format like:

```
url?event=open&signup[customer][first_name]=John&signup[customer][last_name]=Doe&signup[payment_profile][card_number]=xxxxxxxx
```

Is there an easy way to parse this into a c# object? Would it be recommended to parse this in to a `NameValueCollection`, or is it to complex?

I am not familiar with this way of posting data, I don't even know what it is called when you do it like this, anyone care to fill me in? Thanks!

In case you are interested, this is the way stuff get posted:

```
<form method="post" action="https://....">   
  <input type="hidden" name="signup[product][handle]" value="basic" />
  <input type="text" name="signup[customer][first_name]" />
  <input type="text" name="signup[customer][last_name]" />
  <input type="text" name="signup[customer][email]" />
  <input type="text" name="signup[payment_profile][first_name]" />
  <input type="text" name="signup[payment_profile][last_name]" />
  <input type="text" name="signup[payment_profile][card_number]" />
  <input type="text" name="signup[payment_profile][expiration_month]" />
  <input type="text" name="signup[payment_profile][expiration_year]" />
  <input type="submit" value="Sign Up" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse the query string into a NameValueCollection this way:

```
var nvc = new NameValueCollection();
nvc.Add(HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(Request.Params));
```

Comment: This is thin - but since there is no better answer and this ended up being the way I went with this - I'll mark it as the answer!